# Preserve vertex groups and weight paint through remesh

Tags: vertex-weights, retopology, remesh

I have an old, old model of a fantasy creature with pretty bad topology, but I used to spend quite some time getting all the vertex groups and weights right for rigging and animating.

Now, I figured that with all the new fancy remesh methods available, I could just automagically fix the bad topology without having to paint each and every vertex group for each and every bone again.

Sadly, so far it seems that all methods of remeshing (modifier-based and the voxel/quad remesher in the Object Data menu) delete the vertex weight information. (Which, from a technical point of view, I understand, but from a user's point of view I dislike)

Now, is there a way to (approximately, if necessary) transfer my old vertex weights onto my newly remeshed mesh?

Comment: Have a look at the Data Transfer Modifier. I, or someone else, will be able to expand on this, if it's not clear.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out!